# I want to start VB project in Visual Studio 2010 when I am debugging the .ocx

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Well, I am writing an ActiveX component in Visual Studio 2010 and using MFC wizard. When I debug the solution I want to start the actual program ( it is VS 2010) that is going to use that .ocx. In VC++ 6.0, I am able to do that by following steps:

1) Click Project in menubar
2) Select settings in the drop menu
3) Select the debug tab: With Category as General I put the path of VB.exe in box for executable during debug session and in program arguments I would write the path of VB project that uses the said .ocx.

I would like to do same thing, for MFC wizard in Visual Studio 2010. How to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand which is the 'actual program' that uses the ActiveX component you want to debug - can you explain how do you start it?

Comment: It is no different in VS2010, "category" is Debugging, Command setting.  Click around a bit, this was designed to be discoverable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click on the ActiveX project, select 'Properties', then under 'Configuration properties|Debugging' you can set the name of the executable to start ('Command') and its command-line arguments ('Command Arguments').

You should select the EXE of you VB host program (I am not 100% sure what is the program you need to start)

An alternative is to start the program that uses the OCX and then attach the debugger to it: select 'Debug|Attach to process...' in the main menu, and then select the process in the dialog.